# priority_queue with abstract class

Tags: c++, stl, abstract-class, priority-queue

I need to create a priority_queue with abstract class "Organism" as a stored type, because I want both "Animals" and "Plants" in this queue (they derive from "Organism") but I'm not quite sure how can I do this. I've already looked for an answer but unfortunately couldn't find one that worked. Part of my code so far looks like this:

World.h:

```
class World
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    std::priority_queue<Organism, std::vector<Organism>, Compare> organisms;
public:
    World(std::string name);
    ~World();
    virtual void AddOrganism(Organism& organisms);
    void EndTurn();
    void DrawWorld();
};

Compare.h:

class Organism;
class Compare
{
public:
    virtual bool operator()(const Organism& O1, const Organism& O2) const;
};
```

Organism.h:

```
class World;
class Organism
{
protected:
    int strength, initiative, xPos, yPos, age;
    World* world;
    friend class Compare;
public:
    virtual void Move() = 0;
    virtual void Action() = 0;
    virtual void Collision() = 0;
    virtual void DrawMe() = 0;
};
```

and main:

```
int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("xxx"));
    World world("World1");
    Animals animal;
    world.AddOrganism(animal);
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

and AddOrganism method:

```
void World::AddOrganism(Organism& organism) {
    organisms.push(organism);
};
```

When I try to compile this I get "Error C2259   'Organism': cannot instantiate abstract class   ", anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, your queue needs to store pointers or references to `Organism` rather than actual instances of `Organism` [edit: same with the vector btw].

Comment: Btw, rather than storing raw pointers and manually handling the lifetime of the objects in your queue, you can store smart pointers (like `std::unique_ptr<Organism>` for instance) or any kind of class that wraps a pointer/reference to an `Organism`.

Comment: Here: https://ideone.com/NwI4V4 (note that if I hadn't explicitly specified the comparison operator, the priority_queue would compare the addresses to sort its elements rather than the actual objects)